# DNS: why does the server return a CNAME record when asked for an MX

Tags: powershell, dns

I'm starting to take a deep look at how DNS resolves names and I'm having a hard time understanding the answers I'm receiving when using the `Resolve-DnsName` cmdlet. First, I know that the name `id.madeira.gov.pt` is a CNAME for another name (which basically ends up pointing to a web server which hosts several sites). When running my tests, I've started by asking for information about that name with the following command:

```bash
❯ Resolve-DnsName id.madeira.gov.pt

Name                           Type   TTL   Section    NameHost
----                           ----   ---   -------    --------
id.madeira.gov.pt              CNAME  72    Answer     crater.madeira.gov.pt
```

After this test, I was curious about what would happen if I specified the `MX` record type while using the `Resolve-DnsName` cmdlet with the previous name. Initially, I really thought that I shouldn't get any response because the specified name is registered as a CNAME and has no MX entries associated with it. However, that was not what happened...in fact, I've ended up getting the same output as before:

```bash
❯ Resolve-DnsName id.madeira.gov.pt -Type MX

Name                           Type   TTL   Section    NameHost
----                           ----   ---   -------    --------
id.madeira.gov.pt              CNAME  72    Answer     crater.madeira.gov.pt
```

I've also captured the exchange with wireshark and here's the response I've received:

[image: MX query response]

What I'm not getting is why I'm getting a CNAME in the answers section when I've asked for a  MX record...I mean, I'm under the impression that a DNS reply can contain "3 sections":

- Answer: exact record for the query;
- Authority: records that identify authoritative name servers for the query;
- Additional: additional info that might be important for the query

I'm assuming that the cmdlet is working properly, so I'm the one doing wrong assumptions about how DNS queries are answered. Can anyone please help me understand what's going on? I mean, how does the server interpret the question? When you specify the `Type` parameter, shouldn't you get only answers that match the specified name with the specified record type?

Thanks!

Comment: There’s a lapse in your reasoning: `Resolve-DnsName` does not query for `CNAME` records. It queries for `A` and `AAAA` by default. And yet you get the `CNAME` response.

Comment: Nice catch. You're right.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are mostly correct with your descriptions, the only difference is that `CNAME` is handled specially by DNS servers, and this behavior is specified in the [RFC 1034](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1034) (section 3.6.2):

> CNAME RRs cause special action in DNS software.  When a name server
> fails to find a desired RR in the resource set associated with the
> domain name, it checks to see if the resource set consists of a CNAME
> record with a matching class.  If so, the name server includes the CNAME
> record in the response and restarts the query at the domain name
> specified in the data field of the CNAME record.  The one exception to
> this rule is that queries which match the CNAME type are not restarted.

Basically, this means, if you ask for an MX record, and no such record exists, the response will include the CNAME for the original query, and also query the alias given by CNAME in case that includes an MX record, which also will be returned.

Also, if a CNAME exists for a node, no other resource records should exist for that node, so MX should not exist in the first place anyway (from the same section of the RFC):

> If a CNAME RR is present at a node, no other data should be
> present

Comment: Love a good RFC quote

Answer (score 4):

CNAME aliases are not 100% transparent – they only redirect to another name, they do not directly take records from it. So the answer to your query will have the entire CNAME chain *and* the final A or MX record, all in the "Answer" section.

So a query for `A` records would have an answer like this:

```
;; ANSWER SECTION:
id.madeira.gov.pt.      300  IN  CNAME  crater.madeira.gov.pt.
crater.madeira.gov.pt.  299  IN  A      62.28.72.169
```

Both of those records are part of the "answer", and bothare used by the client resolver (e.g. the getaddrinfo() or gethostbyname() function in C) – it gets 62.28.72.169 as the final answer *and* it notes that 'crater.madeira.gov.pt' is the "canonical name" of the host, which programs often also need to know.

Comment: Ok, but as you can see from the image above (wireshark), I'm getting no additional information about the crater.madeira.gov.pt because I'm asking for MX...anyway, you're absolutely right; I've checked the cmdlet again and I do get info about the A record related with the CNAME.

Comment: MX or not MX doesn't really matter, you'll still get the CNAME chain as far as it can be followed (until it reaches the final . When querying for record types that _do_ exist, PowerShell seems to format the results in a strange way (tabular for the first record, but list-mode for all other records) – the above output here was taken from `dig` instead.

Comment: Yes, that seems to be the case.

Comment: @user1686 fyi/OT: The Powershell output is due to the defined format definition and the case we get 1+ objects of different types (DnsRecord_PTR, DnsRecord_A and DnsRecord_SOA). By default, every object type in powershell with more than 4 properties will trigger the list view (like Format-List), except if there's a format definition (for that type) for table view (TableControl via ps1xml OR injected via PSStandardMembers.DefaultDisplayPropertySet OR hardcoded in binary modules) which defines it explicitly.